# Meteor Cordova iOS HCP fails, log says PNG file already exists when it doesn't

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, meteor

I'm running `meteor run ios-device ...` and watching the logs in Xcode. I'm using hot code push on localhost to make css changes that show up immediately in the iOS Simulator device. I add user_white.png to the images folder and in css point a url(...) to it. I get this error, which I don't understand, because user_white.png did not "already exist". Even if I stop-start the simulator in Xcode, this error persists. Any ideas what this error means?

```
2018-07-28 12:48:51.511632-0400 Vium[41847:2439935] Download failure:   
Could not link to cached asset: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 
"“user_white.png” couldn’t be linked to “images” because an item
with the same name already exists."
...
NSFilePath=/Users/opx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6E759135-D5E3- 
4AC0-AF35-92FCC473A61D/data/Containers/Data/Application/D92D9589-4D22-4006- 
8A08-0AC35932E769/Library/NoCloud/meteor/PartialDownload/app/images/user_white.png,
NSUnderlyingError=0x60000024b520 {Error Domain=NSPO
2018-07-28 12:48:51.516594-0400 Vium[41847:2438252] ERROR: 
{"line":36,"column":30,
"sourceURL":"http://localhost:12072/plugins/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp/www/webapp_local_server.js"}
```

Comment: See also https://forums.meteor.com/t/hot-code-push-worked-on-android-not-on-ios/45279 for another, different problem caused by this same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the actual answer: a fix has been merged into the meteor code for the cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp plugin, so as of version 1.7.0 of that plugin, this problem is resolved. See the links in my earlier "answer" and also https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10277 for details, but it's fixed in meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
This is a bug in Meteor -- see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10181 for details, specifically https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp/issues/56. This problem causes iOS Meteor Cordova hot code push to fail. In the cases in which it is causing HCP to fail, the answer below is not sufficient, but the problem also occurs in Xcode debugging in ways that *are* solved by stop/start as described below.

For the record, the answer to this problem is that the error message is a very misleading sounding one, user_white.png is not already existing in a way that's meaningful to the user. The solution is simple enough: stop Xcode/iOS Simulator, stop the Meteor server running on localhost, then rerun `meteor run ios-device ...`.

That rebuild of the server side and subsequent rebuild of the device client in Xcode makes the problem go away. The combination of hot code push and Xcode device simulator apparently don't handle the adding of a new css-referenced image in a way that reports what you really need to know, which is: stop everything and rebuild the app!

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect discovery of a particular problem that causes this message.